# How can I get the value select name

Tags: javascript, dojo

I´m now beginning with programming and I need to know what text would be the value of this code. The JS code would be an "on click" event from this unfoldable list. Thanks you in advance!!

```
 <select name="select1" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select">
        <option value="Artesania">Artesania</option>
        <option value="Banco" selected="selected">Banco</option>
        <option value="Bar">Bar</option>
        <option value="Bodega">Bodega</option>
        <option value="Boutique">Boutique</option>
        <option value="Discoteca">Discoteca</option>
```

Comment: You want the actual value of the select box?

Comment: yes because I want to pass it into query feature layer. I only want to show selected entities. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var selectbox = document.getElementById('select');
selectbox.addEventListener('change', function(){
  console.log(this.value);
  //do whatever you want with the value
});
```

```html
<select name="select1" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select" id='select'>
        <option value="Artesania">Artesania</option>
        <option value="Banco" selected="selected">Banco</option>
        <option value="Bar">Bar</option>
        <option value="Bodega">Bodega</option>
        <option value="Boutique">Boutique</option>
        <option value="Discoteca">Discoteca</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will try it and i´ll tell you

Comment: Oh, I´m new in this. This code is right!. Thanks for your quick reply

Comment: Hi @Kind user . I tried the code you suggested me. Console.log(this.value) replied to me "Cannot read property 'value' of null".

Comment: I know what the problem is, I am calling this before I had created the select. I´ve put the script after the select dojo and it has worked.

Comment: My question is if I have my js code in an external script: where should I put the  document.getElementById? Sorry for my stupid question. Thanks

Comment: @KañiKañissimo You have to put it in the script, which uses that variable :)